# How can I get ellipse coefficient from fitEllipse function of OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, ellipse

I want to extract the red ball from one picture and get the detected ellipse matrix in picture.

Here is my example:
[image]

I threshold the picture, find the contour of red ball by using findContour() function and use fitEllipse() to fit an ellipse.

But what I want is to get coefficient of this ellipse. Because the fitEllipse() return a rotation rectangle (RotatedRect), so I need to re-write this function.

One Ellipse can be expressed as Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F = 0; So I want to get u=(A,B,C,D,E,F) or u=(A,B,C,D,E) if F is 1 (to construct an ellipse matrix).

I read the source code of fitEllipse(), there are totally three SVD process, I think I can get the above coefficients from the results of those three SVD process. But I am quite confused what does each result (variable cv::Mat x) of each SVD process represent and why there are three SVD here?

Here is this function:

```
cv::RotatedRect cv::fitEllipse( InputArray _points )
{
   Mat points = _points.getMat();
   int i, n = points.checkVector(2);
   int depth = points.depth();
   CV_Assert( n >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S));

   RotatedRect box;

   if( n < 5 )
        CV_Error( CV_StsBadSize, "There should be at least 5 points to fit the ellipse" );

    // New fitellipse algorithm, contributed by Dr. Daniel Weiss
    Point2f c(0,0);
    double gfp[5], rp[5], t;
    const double min_eps = 1e-8;
    bool is_float = depth == CV_32F;
    const Point* ptsi = points.ptr<Point>();
    const Point2f* ptsf = points.ptr<Point2f>();

    AutoBuffer<double> _Ad(n*5), _bd(n);
    double *Ad = _Ad, *bd = _bd;

    // first fit for parameters A - E
    Mat A( n, 5, CV_64F, Ad );
    Mat b( n, 1, CV_64F, bd );
    Mat x( 5, 1, CV_64F, gfp );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Point2f p = is_float ? ptsf[i] : Point2f((float)ptsi[i].x, (float)ptsi[i].y);
        c += p;
    }
    c.x /= n;
    c.y /= n;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Point2f p = is_float ? ptsf[i] : Point2f((float)ptsi[i].x, (float)ptsi[i].y);
        p -= c;

        bd[i] = 10000.0; // 1.0?
        Ad[i*5] = -(double)p.x * p.x; // A - C signs inverted as proposed by APP
        Ad[i*5 + 1] = -(double)p.y * p.y;
        Ad[i*5 + 2] = -(double)p.x * p.y;
        Ad[i*5 + 3] = p.x;
        Ad[i*5 + 4] = p.y;
    }

    solve(A, b, x, DECOMP_SVD);

    // now use general-form parameters A - E to find the ellipse center:
    // differentiate general form wrt x/y to get two equations for cx and cy
    A = Mat( 2, 2, CV_64F, Ad );
    b = Mat( 2, 1, CV_64F, bd );
    x = Mat( 2, 1, CV_64F, rp );
    Ad[0] = 2 * gfp[0];
    Ad[1] = Ad[2] = gfp[2];
    Ad[3] = 2 * gfp[1];
    bd[0] = gfp[3];
    bd[1] = gfp[4];
    solve( A, b, x, DECOMP_SVD );

    // re-fit for parameters A - C with those center coordinates
    A = Mat( n, 3, CV_64F, Ad );
    b = Mat( n, 1, CV_64F, bd );
    x = Mat( 3, 1, CV_64F, gfp );
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Point2f p = is_float ? ptsf[i] : Point2f((float)ptsi[i].x, (float)ptsi[i].y);
        p -= c;
        bd[i] = 1.0;
        Ad[i * 3] = (p.x - rp[0]) * (p.x - rp[0]);
        Ad[i * 3 + 1] = (p.y - rp[1]) * (p.y - rp[1]);
        Ad[i * 3 + 2] = (p.x - rp[0]) * (p.y - rp[1]);
    }
    solve(A, b, x, DECOMP_SVD);

    // store angle and radii
    rp[4] = -0.5 * atan2(gfp[2], gfp[1] - gfp[0]); // convert from APP angle usage
    if( fabs(gfp[2]) > min_eps )
        t = gfp[2]/sin(-2.0 * rp[4]);
    else // ellipse is rotated by an integer multiple of pi/2
        t = gfp[1] - gfp[0];
    rp[2] = fabs(gfp[0] + gfp[1] - t);
    if( rp[2] > min_eps )
        rp[2] = std::sqrt(2.0 / rp[2]);
    rp[3] = fabs(gfp[0] + gfp[1] + t);
    if( rp[3] > min_eps )
        rp[3] = std::sqrt(2.0 / rp[3]);

    box.center.x = (float)rp[0] + c.x;
    box.center.y = (float)rp[1] + c.y;
    box.size.width = (float)(rp[2]*2);
    box.size.height = (float)(rp[3]*2);
    if( box.size.width > box.size.height )
    {
        float tmp;
        CV_SWAP( box.size.width, box.size.height, tmp );
        box.angle = (float)(90 + rp[4]*180/CV_PI);
    }
    if( box.angle < -180 )
        box.angle += 360;
    if( box.angle > 360 )
        box.angle -= 360;

    return box;
}
```

The source code link: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The function `fitEllipse` returns a `RotatedRect` that contains all the parameters of the ellipse.

An ellipse is defined by 5 parameters:

- **xc**    : x coordinate of the center
- **yc**    : y coordinate of the center
- **a**     : major semi-axis
- **b**     : minor semi-axis
- **theta** : rotation angle

You can obtain these parameters like:

```
RotatedRect e = fitEllipse(points);

float xc    = e.center.x;
float yc    = e.center.y;
float a     = e.size.width  / 2;    // width >= height
float b     = e.size.height / 2;
float theta = e.angle;              // in degrees
```

You can draw an ellipse with the function `ellipse` using the `RotatedRect`:

```
ellipse(image, e, Scalar(0,255,0));
```

or, equivalently using the ellipse parameters:

```
ellipse(res, Point(xc, yc), Size(a, b), theta, 0.0, 360.0, Scalar(0,255,0));
```

If you need the values of the coefficients of the implicit equation, you can do like (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)):

[image]

So, you can get the parameters you need from the `RotatedRect`, and you don't need to change the function `fitEllipse`.
The [solve](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve) function is used to solve linear systems or least-squares problems. Using the SVD decomposition method the system can be over-defined and/or the matrix src1 can be singular.

For more details on the algorithm, you can see the [paper of Fitzgibbon](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/awf/ellipse/ellipse-pami.pdf) that proposed this fit ellipse method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that worked for me which I based on the other responses on this thread.

```
def getConicCoeffFromEllipse(e):
    # ellipse(Point(xc, yc),Size(a, b), theta)
    xc = e[0][0]
    yc = e[0][1]
    a = e[1][0]/2
    b = e[1][1]/2
    theta = math.radians(e[2])
    # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse
    # Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 is the equation
    A = a*a*math.pow(math.sin(theta),2) + b*b*math.pow(math.cos(theta),2)
    B = 2*(b*b - a*a)*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(theta)
    C = a*a*math.pow(math.cos(theta),2) + b*b*math.pow(math.sin(theta),2)
    D = -2*A*xc - B*yc
    E = -B*xc - 2*C*yc
    F = A*xc*xc + B*xc*yc + C*yc*yc - a*a*b*b
    coef = np.array([A,B,C,D,E,F]) / F
    return coef

def getConicMatrixFromCoeff(c):
    C = np.array([[c[0], c[1]/2, c[3]/2], # [ a, b/2, d/2 ]
                 [c[1]/2, c[2], c[4]/2],  # [b/2,  c, e/2 ]
                 [c[3]/2, c[4]/2, c[5]]])  # [d/2], e/2, f ]
    return C
```