# OpenCV Ellipse fitting: extract parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been investigating the `cv::fitEllipse` function for extracting additional data. I read the article that is cited in the documentation (*Andrew W. Fitzgibbon, R.B.Fisher. A Buyer’s Guide to Conic Fitting. Proc.5th British Machine Vision Conference, Birmingham, pp. 513-522, 1995* which can be found at http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/1995/bmvc-95-050.pdf).

I explicitly want to extract the `a = [Axx Axy Ayy ...]` matrix, but the code is so optimized that I cannot identify where these values are. I'm not even sure that the function fom OpenCV 3.0 implements that algorithm. For instance, they only estimate 5 parameters, while the cited paper refers to 6 parameters.

Does anyone has an hint on that?

Alternatively, does anyone have a hint on how I can measure how good my estimated ellipse fits the model? For now, I was relying on the fact that `F(a, x) = 0`, where `a` is my ellipse parameter vector, `a = [Axx Axy Ayy ...]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get ellipse coefficient from fitEllipse function of OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793703/how-can-i-get-ellipse-coefficient-from-fitellipse-function-of-opencv)

Comment: The original fitzgibbon algorithm has been the one of "Dr. Daniel Weiss". You can see in the linked answer how to get the parameters you're looking for from the result of `fitEllipse` (remember to convert the angles from degrees to radians). If that answer doesn't fully address your question, please let me know.

Comment: Do you know some details about Dr. Daniel Weiss's ellipse fitting algorithm? By the way, who is Dr. Daniel Weiss, I can not find any information about him.