# Algorithm of ellipse fitting in OpenCV

Tags: algorithm, opencv, curve-fitting, ellipse

I read the code of ellipse fitting in OpenCV, the following link gives the source code of ellipse fitting in OpenCV: http://lpaste.net/161378.

I want to know some details about ellipse fitting in OpenCV, but I can not find any documents of the algorithm. In the comments, it said " New fitellipse algorithm, contributed by Dr. Daniel Weiss". But I can not find any paper about ellipse fitting of Dr. Daniel Weiss.

I have some questions of the algorithm:

1. Why does the algorithm need re-fit. It first fit for parameters A - E, and then re-fit for parameters A - C with those center coordinates.
2. Ellipse need the satisfy the constraint of 4*a*b - c^2 > 0, how does the algorithm satisfy it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering about this myself since I've discovered that the algorithm is bugged. See this bug-report: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6544

I tried to find any relevant papers by Dr. Daniel Weiss and failed.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this repo useful (with pip set-up):

https://github.com/bdhammel/least-squares-ellipse-fitting

which works from an upgrade to the Fitzgibbon algorithm (as a starting point), as authored by Halir here:

https://github.com/bdhammel/least-squares-ellipse-fitting/blob/master/media/WSCG98.pdf

I've since tested this a little and seems to be very effective.  Note that the 'example' on the repo home page is out of date -- look to the example.py module in the code itself for usage that seems to work as to module imports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the OpenCV function [cv::fitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa) mentions this paper:

[Andrew W Fitzgibbon and Robert B Fisher. A buyer's guide to conic fitting. In Proceedings of the 6th British conference on Machine vision (Vol. 2), pages 513–522. BMVA Press, 1995.](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/MY_DAI_OLD_FTP/rp810.pdf)

Also related link: [OpenCV Ellipse fitting: extract parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176179/opencv-ellipse-fitting-extract-parameters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this paper does not have enough details of ellipse fitting.