# OpenCV Inverse Matrix

Tags: python, opencv, matrix

somehow I get different results using numpy's `linalg.inv` and OpenCv's `Mat::inv`, e.g. given a matrix `S`:

```
[747.8561839552103, 359.9317804054358, 204.6165451419812, 241.7376332155144, 126.132733370211, 81.57610562583466;
  359.9317804054358, 204.6165451419812, 140.4788277943211, 126.132733370211, 80.55127348381332, 47.7506303038364;
  204.6165451419812, 140.4788277943211, 116.7472083846913, 80.55127348381332, 63.86033402962857, 35.56970826526131;
  241.7376332155144, 126.132733370211, 80.55127348381332, 81.57610562583466, 47.7506303038364, 29.55106507912703;
  126.132733370211, 80.55127348381332, 63.86033402962857, 47.7506303038364, 35.56970826526131, 20.31193086803655;
  81.57610562583466, 47.7506303038364, 35.56970826526131, 29.55106507912703, 20.31193086803655, 12]
```

OpenCV `S.inv()` results in

```
[-19562262532715.65, 137.3094415699439, -44015090698406.93, 78249050130618.84, 88030181396160.73, -78249050129617.47;
 124.2797501878658, 19.14093204142484, 301.2737811201993, -531.0713785028685, -686.3332686269306, 655.5356524828615;
 -44015090698424.45, 330.6065529853437, -99033954070961.39, 176060362793110.9, 198067908140346.2, -176060362790691.7;
 78249050130642.06, -583.2397919514979, 176060362793093.2, -312996200521532.5, -352120725583424.9, 312996200517305.3;
 88030181396256.19, -744.9706630355842, 198067908140482.2, -352120725583702.1, -396135816277430.2, 352120725578288.9;
 -78249050129732.52, 707.7008280168318, -176060362790880.5, 312996200517672.6, 352120725578424.8, -312996200512573.6]
```

numpy's `linalg.inv` results in:

```
[[2685109332201.37, -23.46, 6041495997420.42, -10740437328763.82, -12082991994731.51, 10740437328597.41]
 [-32.56, 19.14, -51.60, 96.23, 19.43, 28.24]
 [6041495997407.60, -31.13, 13593365994129.85, -24165983989574.97, -27186731988120.73, 24165983989366.80]
 [-10740437328747.65, 59.84, -24165983989589.86, 42961749314884.59, 48331967978891.43, -42961749314440.71]
 [-12082991994663.29, -21.50, -27186731988024.93, 48331967978691.32, 54373463976152.90, -48331967978849.60]
 [10740437328516.33, 64.62, 24165983989235.66, -42961749314181.06, -48331967978757.62, 42961749314608.99]]
```

Okay, now some detail of how I stumbled across this:
I am working on a routine to fit an ellipse given a point set; I have transferred code from: http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html to C++:

```
  template <typename InputIt>                                                     
  std::array<double, 6> fit_ellipse(InputIt first, InputIt last) {                
       typedef double value_type;                                                  

       auto num_points = std::distance(first, last);                               

       cv::Mat_<value_type> D(num_points, 6);                                      
       size_t row(0);                                                              
       for (auto it(first); it != last; ++it, ++row) {                             
           auto &point = *it;                                                      
           auto &x = std::get<0>(point);                                           
           auto &y = std::get<1>(point);                                           
           D(row, 0) = x * x;                                                      
           D(row, 1) = x * y;                                                      
           D(row, 2) = y * y;                                                      
           D(row, 3) = x;                                                          
           D(row, 4) = y;                                                          
           D(row, 5) = 1.f;                                                        
       }                                                                           

       auto S = D.t() * D;                                                         

       cv::Mat_<value_type> C = cv::Mat_<value_type>::zeros(6, 6);                 
       C(0, 2) = C(2, 0) = 2; C(1, 1) = -1;                                        

       cv::Mat Sinv = S.inv();                                                     
       std::cout << "Sinv:" << Sinv << std::endl;                      
       cv::Mat_<value_type> E, V; cv::eigen(Sinv * C, E, V);                       
       int n;                                                                      
       cv::minMaxIdx(cv::abs(E), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &n);                   

       return {{V(n, 0), V(n, 1), V(n, 2), V(n, 3), V(n, 4), V(n, 5)}};            
   }
```

To comparison the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    Sinv = inv(S)
    print("Sinv: %s" % Sinv)
    E, V = eig(np.dot(Sinv, C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    a = V[:,n]
    return a
```

The code is run initializing following points:

```
TEST(fit_ellipse, test_example) {
    namespace bmc = boost::math::constants;

    typedef std::array<double, 2> point_type;
    std::vector<point_type> points;

    auto arc = .8;
    for (size_t i(0); i < 12; ++i) {
        auto r = i * arc * bmc::pi<double>() / 12;
        points.push_back({1.5 * std::cos(r) + 2, std::sin(r) + 1});
    }
    auto a = fit_ellipse(points.begin(), points.end());
    std::cout << "Parameters: "
    for (auto &p : a)
        std::cout << p << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Same in Python:

```
R = np.arange(0, arc * np.pi, arc * np.pi / 12)
x = 1.5 * np.cos(R) + 2
y = np.sin(R) + 1.
print("Parameters: %s" % fitEllipse(x,y))
```

Any Idea what I am missing out?

Comment: You know that OpenCV already has [fitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitellipse) (which is an improvement of Fitzgibbon method)?

Comment: I thaught of using directly the quadratic curve parameters to determine the goodness of fit, wanted to use ransac to eliminate outliers.

Comment: Ok. I think that the different results are due to numerical issues, handled differently in the two implementations. In fact, in Matlab the result is different from both. The problem seems to be that the matrix is ill-conditioned. Matlab gives a condition number of 4.6471e+17, when a well-conditioned matrix has it around 1

Comment: Try adding a small value (like 10e-5) to the diagonal, results should be more similar

Comment: Oh, yes, that could help, thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: Well, still does not work, anyways, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793703/how-can-i-get-ellipse-coefficient-from-fitellipse-function-of-opencv could help me retrieve parameters and use OpenCV's fitEllipse.

Comment: You can always check if a matrix inversion is good by doing A * A^-1, since it should equal the identity matrix. In your case it's odd that the matrix is singular, could you share your values of x & y ? You might need to normalise them.

Comment: maybe floating point precision, check whether they are running on the same precision.