# Python: How to check whether a Circle has equal radius along all 360 degrees

Tags: python, geometry, image-segmentation, radius

Using Python, I want to check whether a circle has an equal radius along all 360 degrees. Actually, I have segmented a circular shape from an image and then want to check whether it has a same-sized and equal radius along all the 360 degrees or not.

Can someone kindly help and tell how to do that?

Comment: You could maybe use OpenCV

Comment: Do you know how to do that in OpenCV? Also, is possible with Python-OpenCV? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know, I have never used it, but in terms of dealing with recognising images that is probably about all there is.

Comment: This question seems a bit broad for SO - try using a CV library to read the image, see if you can identify the circle, and so on - and then come back and ask about any specific problems you come across.

Comment: OK. I can do segmentation but have no idea about the other task. Can it (checking equal radius)  be done in MATLAB?

Comment: doesn't seem that broad to me... anyway, if you already segmented your region of interest I'd look at [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops). `eccentricity` is probably the property you need. MATLAB has a pretty similar api too

Answer (score 3):

In Python, OpenCV is a strong choice for an imaging library. You'd want to fit a contour to the circle and use moments to check the properties. You can fit an ellipse and see how close the major and minor axis of the ellipse match.

See this [tutorial/docs](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html) for details.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793703/how-can-i-get-ellipse-coefficient-from-fitellipse-function-of-opencv) should help.