# How to find perimeter of multiple ellipses in an image? OpenCV,Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that has multiple placentomes(objects in white and grey). The placentomes aren't full ellipses. I have already estimated full ellipses using fitEllipse in OpenCV. However, need help finding the perimeter of the estimated ellipses.

[Image with multiple placentomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hacw7.png)

[Image with drawn ellipses in red on the placentomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzDyF.png)

Below is the code I'm using to draw the ellipse onto the placentomes :-

```
img = cv2.imread('placentome.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# Find countours of placentomes
cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

# Draws ellipse onto objects using the contours found

for cnt in cnts:
  ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
  cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0,0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to calculate the perimeter of the red ellipses in your image. More explanation would be useful.

This question is already partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798273/5707440). I will copy the important parts:
"The function `fitEllipse` returns a `RotatedRect` that contains all the parameters of the ellipse.

An ellipse is defined by 5 parameters:

- **xc**    : x coordinate of the center
- **yc**    : y coordinate of the center
- **a**     : major semi-axis
- **b**     : minor semi-axis
- **theta** : rotation angle

You can obtain these parameters like:

```
RotatedRect e = fitEllipse(points);

float xc    = e.center.x;
float yc    = e.center.y;
float a     = e.size.width  / 2;    // width >= height
float b     = e.size.height / 2;
float theta = e.angle;              // in degrees
```

Obtaining the perimeter of an ellipse is not a trivial mathematical problem. An approximate solution for the perimeter can be derived with the equation of Ramanujan:

[image: equation of Ramanujan]